# multiply a matrix by an integer in python

Tags: python

I know how to multiply two matrices(under a class). Below I show my code. However I can not seem to figure out how to multiply a matrix and an integer in Python.

**Update**:
Example of a matrix.

```
L=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
3*L
# [[1,6],[9,12],[15,18]]

def __mul__(self,other):
    '''this will multiply two predefined matrices where the number of
    columns in the first is equal to the number of rows in the second.'''
    L=self.L
    L2=other.L
    result=[]
    if len(L[0])==len(L2):
        for i in range(len(L)):
            row=[]
            for j in range(len(L2[0])):
                var=0 
                for k in range(len(L2)):
                    var=var+L[i][k]*L2[k][j]
                row=row+[var]
            result = result+[row]
        return matrix(result)
    else:
        raise ValueError('You may not only multiply m*n * n*q matrices.')
```

Comment: What data type are you using for the matrix?

Comment: If you make considerable modifications to your question, please try to make such one more recognizable (using words like edit, update). Thanks

Comment: Even if you like to represent the `matrix` as a `list of list` (instead of using proper package), your `matrix` `matrix` multiplication is way too complicated. And obviously a `matrix` multiplication with `integer` should be even more streamlined one. Thanks

Comment: Homework? If so re tag as such. You may get more answers if your are able to show some actual code what you have done so far (even based on your over complicated `matrix` `matrix` code. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you mean by `matrix`, but with [numpy](http://numpy.org/), it would be just like:

```
import numpy as np

M= np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [6, 7, 8]])
2* M
# array([[ 0,  2,  4],
#        [ 6,  8, 10],
#        [12, 14, 16]])
```

or

```
M= np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
# matrix([[1, 2],
#         [3, 4]])
2* M
# matrix([[2, 4],
#         [6, 8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
[[elem*3 for elem in row] for row in L]
[[3, 6], [9, 12], [15, 18]]
```